# Slow Looper: doFrame is 4274ms late because of 3 msg, msg 1 took 4258ms

Tags: android, retrofit

I am using retrofit 2 for sending my data to store in MySQL database. I have some problem in my code. How to solve this error

```
W/Looper: Slow Looper: doFrame is 4274ms late because of 3 msg, msg 1 took 4258ms (late=10ms h=android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewRootHandler c=android.view.View$PerformClick)
```

I am also using thread in my code.

My Manifest File:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.education.education">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".HomeActivity"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".RegisterActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

And My Response Code. First time i am trying without handler after that it will give this error that time many of answers suggest to add the handler. after adding this handler. same error is occurred. How to solve this problem:

```
            Call<User> call = MainActivity.apiInstance.PerfomUserRegister(name, email, phone, password, uid);
            call.equals(new Callback<User>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<User> call, final Response<User> response) {


                    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            User user = response.body();
                            String status = user.getResponse();
                            if(status.equals("ok"))
                            {
                                Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Registration Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                            else if(status.equals("failed")){
                                Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Registration Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }
                    }, 1000);



                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<User> call, Throwable t) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onFailure: " + t);
                }
            });
```

I have this problem how to solve it.